# Create 2 sub Divs inside of 1 Div using JS function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, appendchild

I am building a web app and I am having an issue. I am building a flash card app that displays a card with a word, and I will later add CSS to make a flip transition to reveal a definition for that word. Currently I am generating a 2 new divs ( 1 for the word, and one for the definition ), all within a "div1". Div1 is a full width container that is used to hold all the cards.

I am trying to make it so that my function will create a div within "Div1" called "Cardcontainer", and within that div are 2 sub divs ( 1 for the word and 1 for the definition ). I cant figure out how to do this. I am able to generate 2 divs and place them next to each other, but to get my css trick to work, I need 2 divs ( word and definition ) inside of ( and filling 100% of ) a "Cardcontainer" div, which is generated each time I click the "create card" button.

The reason I need to do this is because I need to position the 2 divs ( word and definition ) overlapping each other for the css trick to work. Because I am creating 2 separate divs without them being inside of a "Cardcontainer", I am unable to make this css trick work.

here is a link to the css tutorial... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV8MVmtgmoY

**Current Structure for the button**
Creates 2 divs ( word and def ) inside of Div1, which is a container that is just used to hold all the cards and separate them from the other page content.

**What I need from the button**
Create 1 div called "Cardcontainer", which holds 2 divs ( word and def ). This "Cardcontainer" still needs to be generated within the "Div1" that I am currently using.

I have the following function..

```
function appendDiv() {
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += '<div class="word">'
                +  document.getElementById('word').value
                + '</div><div class="definition">'
                + document.getElementById('def').value +
                "</div>";


        }
```

Here is my HTML...

```
    <input type="text" id="def" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control" placeholder="Definition"style="margin: 10px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="clearText()">Clear Text</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="appendDiv()">Create Card</button>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <br>
```

Here is my CSS. Because I am doing it this way, my CSS is a little messy. once I figure out how to do this correctly, it should be fine....

```
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

    .btn {
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    div {
        background-color:lightcoral;
        margin: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 225;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 35px;
        padding-bottom: 35px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        overflow-y: auto;

    }

    #div1 {
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: start;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


    span {
        width: 500px;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .input-group-text {
        color: white;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;

    }

    .form-control {
        width: 25%;
    }

    #def {
        width: 60%;
        height: 50px;
    }


    div.word {

        backface-visibility: hidden;
        background-color:lightsteelblue;
        margin: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 225;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-top: 75px;
        padding-bottom: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
         border-width: 4px;
  border-color:lightseagreen;
  border-style: solid;
  justify-content: center;
    }

    ;

    div.definition {
        background: green;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        margin: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 225;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
font-weight: lighter;
float: left;
border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another div with class "cardholder".

```
function appendDiv() {
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += '<div class="cardholder"><div class="word">'
                +  document.getElementById('word').value
                + '</div><div class="definition">'
                + document.getElementById('def').value +
                "</div></div>";


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using **appendChild**. After that you can add the class you want and the value of the div by using **div.innerHTML**. If you want to set the text in a p element then you can appendChild a p tag in the definition div.

You can see the demo at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tmach/pen/xxxmyJG)

Here is the new JS function:

```
function appendDiv() {
  let div1 = document.getElementById('div1');

  //Container div
  const divContainer = document.createElement("div");
  divContainer.classList.add("Cardcontainer");
  div1.appendChild(divContainer);

  // 2 Divs in container
  const divWord = document.createElement("div");
  const divDef = document.createElement("div");

  divWord.classList.add("word");
  divDef.classList.add("definition");
  divDef.innerHTML = document.getElementById('def').value;

  divContainer.appendChild(divWord);
  divContainer.appendChild(divDef);
}
```